# Poweredge 2650 RAC Card setup

Tags: remote-access, dell, dell-poweredge, password-recovery

I have a Poweredge 2650 with RAC 3.37 installed.  Recently acquired the server and I have found some difficulty in setting up the RAC.  On booting normally you can setup the IP, Gateway, Netmask and DNS in a regular boot up "Press Control + D to setup Remote Access" screen.

There is no where on this menu that allows you to set a RAC password!

So i set the system/setp passwords in the F2 setup bios page.
no luck here either.

Throughout the trial I can ALWAYS get to the RAC login page.

"root"/"calvin"&systempassword do nothing for me.

Any thoughts guys/gals(i have to assume there atleast a few female geeks out there...)

Bios Rev of 2650 is A21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to sell the server and buy a new one.  Never found reliable information to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

A few quick searches suggest that if root/calvin isn't working when you use the racadm tool, your best bet may be to disconnect the battery on the RAC and let it drain to see if it resets to factory defaults.

All of the references to the racadm tool, whether going in via telnet or serial require that you authenticate yourself (specifically have the ConfigureDracIII permission bit).  I assume the problem here is that you're working with a system that you have physical but not root access to.

I did find this musing about using the on-board jumpers to do the same thing:

http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Alt/alt.sys.pc-clone.dell/2006-04/msg00949.html

but it was speculation on the part of the original poster.

Comment: Absolutely correct, i do have physical access.  I will unplug the battery when I get home and give it 10 mins to discharge.

Comment: Hmmm, it doesnt look like there is a battery on the RAC for the 2650.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start here, with the Dell manuals: http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/RAC/en/is/index.htm